# Fatal error: Uncaught WC_Data_Exception: Invalid billing email address

Tags: woocommerce, xampp

I had my woocommerce website hosted on a domain, after hosting it on my xampp local server it shows this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught WC_Data_Exception: Invalid billing email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by changing woocommerce from email and admin email.

Comment: where can i see it on database?

Comment: Go to `wp_options` change `admin_email` to your email.

Answer (score 3):

After googling for hours these processes worked. This type of error is coming usually when you run the backup on the local server using plugin like All In One Migration Tool

1. Go to the `wp_options` (your prefix might be different)
2. change the `admin_email` to a real email
3. Come back to your dashboard and refresh the page
4. Go to `Setting > General Setting > Administration Email Address` (Now the Administration Email Address is what you put in the database)
5. Now you are here (Setting > General Setting > Administration Email Address) don't change anything just hit the save changes button at the bottom.
6. Now from your dashboard go to `User > Edit Admin` if the email box is not updated automatically change the email here also.
7. Scroll down to the bottom and click Update Profile

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on localhost after migrating (with the All In One Migration plugin) a live website to a local environment. So, locally my administrator email changed to `admin@localhost`. This error was not fixed even after changing the administrator email address to the actual email.

**Solution:** I fixed this error by using ***Find and replace*** option in `phpmyadmin` on `wp_woocommerce_sessions` table. Also attached the screenshot.

[image]